# Rails 4 bootstrap-sass and simple user nav

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple user nav with bootstrap-sass. Here is my application layout...

## app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>WcApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="brand" href="/">WritingCenter@ABtech</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><%= link_to "Instructors", instructors_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Tutors", tutors_path %></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the view I am getting. I have used code similar to this with twitter bootstrap gem and have a hoizontal view of each list item, which is what I want. A list of my 'li' across the top of the screen.

Any help appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Did you check in your browsers debug tools to see if the bootstrap css is included?

Comment: I checked things out using firebug and I don't see any mention of bootstrap, only application.css and scaffold.css. Thats one of the things I'm not sure about, should I see a mention of bootstrap? I was thinking by adding the import statments that added it to application.css.

Comment: you could check for bootstrap related styles in your application.css